# How to send String data to kafka producer using Reactive Kafka?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api, reactive-kafka

I have a data in string format. I need to send it to kafka producer to a specific partition but using reactive kafka ie making async call. How to achieve this using code ? I checked reactive kafka docs but unfortunately I dont have much idea about Java Rx(Mono/Flux) etc.

It would be great if some one can help. Any questions needing more details are welcomed.

I am able to do this in non-rective way.

Comment: If you want just async send, why don't you use just use Kafka client, do you really need Java Rx. The KafkaProducer by default calls it asynchronously only.

Comment: Okay thanks for that. Actually I was checking Kafka Reactive library and was curious to try it.